# Getting forbidden error while accessing the sharepoint page in core application using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, netcoreapp3.1

I want to get the data from share point list, I tried to get the data using api in core application. I used that api link in web browser i didn't get any issue, i got a sharepoint list datas. but if i use that same api link in program I got a forbidden error. I used different methods to access the sharepoint page in core application, but every method returned with forbidden error.

Suggest the idea to how to access the sharepoint list in core appplication using api.

I can access the sharepoint page I have a member access, why I can't access the page programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

When you access SharePoint in a browser, you must be already authenticated (i.e. you are logged in using your username/password or whatever). Therefore, the browser passes your credentials with every call automatically, including the case when you make requests to API endpoints using browser.

When you access SharePoint using API programmatically, you need to authenticate. I.e. pass some credentials with every request you make to the SharePoint API.

Comment: I tried with credentials too(microsoft's username and password) but it returned with a forbidden error.